# How to upload an image to Amazon s3 bucket using Java in Android?

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload an image I took from the camera to the s3 bucket.

```
CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
getApplicationContext(),
"us-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
Regions.US_WEST_2
);

 AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new AWSCredentials() {
        @Override
        public String getAWSAccessKeyId() {
            return "XXXXXXX";
        }

        @Override
        public String getAWSSecretKey() {
            return "XXXXXXX";
        }
    });


    TransferUtility transferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3Client,getApplicationContext());

transferUtility.upload(MY_BUCKET,file.getName(),file);
```

My pool is in us-west-2 but my bucket region is in Asia pacific Sydney.

Running the above code crashes and gives me the error below.

```
Java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE flg=0x4000010 (has extras) } in com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferService$NetworkInfoReceiver@744215
                                                                                 at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$-android_app_LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args_50043(LoadedApk.java:1282)
                                                                                 at android.app.-$Lambda$FilBqgnXJrN9Mgyks1XHeAxzSTk.$m$0(Unknown Source:4)
                                                                                 at android.app.-$Lambda$FilBqgnXJrN9Mgyks1XHeAxzSTk.run(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:769)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10084 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.
                                                                                 at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1948)
```

I have added permissons and services in the manifest file. How can I fix this and send an image to s3 bucket in Asia pacific sydney.

I have these permissions under manifest file -

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: what are the permissions are you added in manifest

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Comment: You are also using the incorrect constructor. You should be using `credentialsProvider` as the input to s3Client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error clearly states, you need to add `android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` permission in your Manifest

Comment: check caps letter

Comment: @alansamuel as @N.V.Rao suggested your permission is `ANDROID.PERMISSION.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` whereas it should be `android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE`